# Read() function doesnt read the entire data on serial communication

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

Here is my code

```
void Reading_TtyS0()
{
     int ret;
     char mypipe_ttyS0[80] = {0};
     fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

     ret = read(fd, ttyS0_mypipe , 80 );
     printf(ret = %d\n", ret);
     if (ret > 0)
     {
         perror("Message Log, Reading /dev/ttyS0");
         printf("Message Log, Reading /dev/ttyS0 with data = %s\n",  ttyS0_mypipe);
         tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
         ret = 0;
     }
}
```

My output is

ret = 8

Message Log, Reading /dev/ttyS0: Success

Message Log, Reading /dev/ttyS0 with data = 0066923:

I am reading only 8 bytes instead of 80.

I should receive 0066923:12:13:134:1134:112344:333...(till 80 bytes)

The output on gtkterm and I am receiving the complete data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read()` does not necessarily return the number of bytes it was told to read.

So loop around read until you got what you want:

```
 char mypipe_ttyS0[80] = {0};
 fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

 size_t bytes_to_read = 80;
 size_t bytes_read = 0;
 while (bytes_to_read > 0)
 {
   ssize_t result = read(fd, ttyS0_mypipe + bytes_read, bytes_to_read);
   if (-1 == result)
   {
     if ((EWOULDBLOCK == errno) || (EAGAIN == errno))
     {
       continue;
     }

     perror("read() failed");

     break;
   } 
   else (0 == result)
   {
     fprintf(stderr, "Connection closed.");

     break;
   }

   printf("Read %zd bytes.\n", result);

   bytes_to_read -= result;
   bytes_read += result;
 }

 ....
```

Comment: Check for EWOULDBLOCK and EAGAIN? Why is that? read() is a blocking call here. fcntl() sets implicitly O_NONBLOCK to zero. Maybe it is better to use EINTR check?

Comment: @Michael: No, it surely isn't a non-blocking call, and those parts of the code are needless on this serial connection and will never be accessed. I just added it to clarify what I mentioned in my comments to *Chirag Desai*'s answer. It's just the generic way to use `read()`.

Comment: @akl It was not mine down. I'm ok with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its non-blocking read operation, so its possible that read will return whatever data received in the buffer at the moment.

You have to loop through the read until all data received.

```
 int ret;
 char mypipe_ttyS0[80] = {0};
 fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

 int i = 5; // let say iterate 5 times
 int bytes_to_read = 80;
 ret = 0;
 while (i > 0)
 {
    ret += read(fd, mypipe_ttyS0 + ret , bytes_to_read );
    printf(ret = %d\n", ret);

    bytes_to_read -= ret;
    if(bytes_to_read == 0)
    {
         break;
    } 
    ++i;
 }

    if (bytes_to_read == 0)
    {
         perror("Message Log, Reading /dev/ttyS0");
         printf("Message Log, Reading /dev/ttyS0 with data = %s\n",  ttyS0_mypipe);
         tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
         ret = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why not changed the `while()` condition to be `(bytes_to_read > 0)`? Couldn't it take more then "*let' say*" `5` times to get all data? Also the code misses to check the result of `read()` for error and end-of-file/connection-closed.

Comment: We can put `(bytes_to_read > 0)` but in that case the read operation will become clocking. And yeas true I did not check for `read()` errors as the loop is going to end in 5 iterations anyway...

Comment: The `read()` as shown in the OP's example is **not** a non-blocking call. It is a blocking call, as it always returns at least one byte. If it would be a non-blocking call then `read()` might return `-1` with `errno` set to `EWOULDBLOCK`. Please see `man 3 read` for details.

Comment: Also your code overwrites `ttyS0_mypipe` with every iteration.

Comment: See @alk , Azeemali Hashmani doesnot have issue with his code, He wants to know why read is incomplete. And I think he got his answer ..